# Bitfinex get credits and convert timestamp to JS Date

Tags: api, timestamp, javascript, bitfinex

I'm fetching my active credits in BFX and trying to discover when I'll have my funding back. This is a response example:

`/v1/credits`

```
[{
    amount: "294.4316181",
    currency: "USD",
    id: 15778083,
    period: 2,
    rate: "16.816",
    status: "ACTIVE",
    timestamp: "1454846632.0"
}, ...
]
```

But `new Date(1454846632.0)` returns a very old date, what makes me think this timestamp isn't there to be converted into a real date at all.

I am doing something wrong? How can I discover the remaining time of a credit I provided?

Comment: This is kind of off-topic, as converting timestamps is more of a regular programming question than a cryptocurrency specific issue. However, the question is well-written, got an answer quickly, and might be of use to others, so I'll not vote to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with the timestamp, it's with your method of converting the timestamp to local time.

As [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date-with-javascript) describes, convert it this way:

```
var dt = new Date(0);
dt.setUTCSeconds(1454846632);
console.log(dt.toString());
```

Which prints `Sun Feb 07 2016 07:03:52 GMT-0500 (EST)`.